# Awaiting a task is taking forever or not working at all

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I must be missing something,

```
var t2 = new Task<bool>(() =>
         {
             return UserName == "Admin";
         });

bool x = await t2;
```

The `bool x = await t2;` is never finished, `x` doesn't receive anything (while I made sure that UserName is equal to "Admin"), don't know exactly what is going on, please someone can explain to me .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't started the task. `await` will wait until it completes, but it's never going to complete if it doesn't get started.

Perhaps you wanted [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run), which creates *and starts* a task? (I assume that in reality, your task does something more useful...)

Comment: Even a t2.start() would help to start the task and then it awaits the completion

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: Indeed, but if you're going to create and then immediately start a task, you might as well use `Task.Run` in the first place :)

Comment: @ Jon Skeet agreed, was trying the minimal current code change :)

Comment: The correct way to create and start a task is using `Task.Run` http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you have to start the task, but better to use the task factory

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return UserName == "Admin";
        });

bool x = await t2;
```

or use Task.Run()

[Task.Run vs Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)